# Error after disable Index in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to do Bulk Insert, but it takes a long time. My Idea is to disable Index on the table, to do INSERTs a little bit faster. But after that I get this error:

> Error: The query processor is unable to produce a plan because the index `CRMD_MKTTG_TG_I~0` on table or view '`CRMD_MKTTG_TG_I`' is disabled.

I am generating my table with this script:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [CRMD_MKTTG_TG_I](
    [CLIENT] [nvarchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [GUID] [varbinary](16) NOT NULL,
    [TG_GUID] [varbinary](16) NULL,
    [BP_GUID] [varbinary](16) NULL,
    [BP_ORG] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [BP_DEL] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [REL_GUID] [varbinary](16) NULL,
    [RELATIONSHIP] [nvarchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [TYPE_BP_GUID] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [TYPE_REL_GUID] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [ROW_NUMBER] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [CRMD_MKTTG_TG_I~0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CLIENT] ASC,
    [GUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

any idea?

Comment: Disabling clustered index to do things faster?

Comment: You may wish to take a step back and ask the question "How do I speed up a bulk insert on this table given this data", with details of the data (including the *order* of the source data with regard to the clustered index columns), the number of rows, the time it's currently taking, and your bcp statement. It might help to do a bit more diagnosis in advance to figure out what's slow -- there's no point dropping indexes if you're being constrained by your network bandwidth, for example.

Comment: CRMD_MKTTG_TG_I~0 is the cluistered index. you cannot disable it.

Comment: That PK is just strange to me.   Why is GUID alone not enough for a PK?  Why not just let [ROW_NUMBER] be the PK?    Insert in the order of the PK to minimize index fragmentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`[CRMD_MKTTG_TG_I~0]` is a clustered index. If you disable it, you can't access to the data (select, insert, update, delete data).

Read [Disable Indexes and Constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177456.aspx):

- Disabling an index prevents user access to the index
- and for clustered indexes to the underlying table data.

In this case, you can only:

- drop the clustered index and transform it into a heap,
- query your table
- and then create a new clustered index.

Comment: How about: **`ALTER INDEX [CRMD_MKTTG_TG_I~0] REBUILD`**?

Comment: You can use rebuild to enable a disabled index. however while the clustered index is disabled, you still can't query the table, hence the OP error.